Audio device profile is changed by different applications
Since recently I have a issue where starting an application that needs access to my microphone changes my audio profile set up in pavucontrol from "Pro Audio" to something else.
This specifically happens when using Discord, for example. Every time I join a channel I need to go into pavucontrol, change the profile back to "Pro Audio" and then I have to explicitly set up my input/output in discord to that device as well. Setting the input/output to "Default" in discord seems to crash the audio server completely.
I'm relatively new to the linux audio world but as far as I can tell Discord is using PulseAudio, which I have available with pipewire-pulse (see config below). But it shouldn't change the device profile I'm running, right?
When I check pw-cli e <device-id> Profile I can see that the profile is in fact available, selected and also set to save.
Any advice on how to debug/fix this is highly appreciated.
I'm using NixOS and my audio device is a Focusrite Scarlett Solo 4th Gen.
This is my Nix config regarding audio:
configuration.nix:
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
{
  hardware.pulseaudio.enable = false;
  security.rtkit.enable = true;

  services.pipewire = {
    enable = true;
    alsa = {
      enable = true;
      support32Bit = true;
    };
    pulse.enable = true;
    wireplumber.enable = true;
    jack.enable = true;
    extraConfig = {
      pipewire."92-low-latency" = {
        context.properties = {
          default.clock.rate = 192000;
          default.clock.allowed-rates = [ 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000 ];
          default.clock.quantum = 512;
          default.clock.min-quantum = 32;
          default.clock.max-quantum = 1024;
        };
      };
    };
  };

  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    pavucontrol
    helvum
    alsa-utils
  ];
}

easyeffects.nix:
{ pkgs, config, ... }: {

  services.easyeffects = {
    enable = true;
    preset = "default";
  };

  home.file = {
    ".config/easyeffects/output/default.json" = {
      source = config.lib.file.mkOutOfStoreSymlink ../loose-configs/easyeffects/output/default.json;
    };
  };
}


I have the same problem after updating Wireplumber to 0.5.6, but after I've downgraded to 0.5.5 the issue disappeared.

I downgraded using a nix overlay and now it's working as expected. Thank you!

Via pacman -Ud I downgraded these two packages for myself and I had to go through Arch Linux Archive because I didn't have the old cached packages.
libwireplumber (0.5.6-1 => 0.5.5-1)
https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/libwireplumber/
wireplumber (0.5.6-1 => 0.5.5-1)
https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/w/wireplumber/
I used the wiki  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Downgrading_packages

This is fixed now!
Go upgrade -> https://pipewire.pages.freedesktop.org/wireplumber/resources/releases.html

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Also, this could/should be an edit to your earlier answer. - From Review
